# Flex items align on phones - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with the allignment of the flexbox grid items on phones - using Bootstrap 4.4.1.
The items are going to more and more to right and I want to have them in the center (all of them). Here is the image.
[image: Image of the problem]
And here is the code (HTML with bootstrap classes):

```
            <div class="d-sm-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3 justify-content-center">
                <div class="p-2 bd-highlight pr-4 text-center"><h1>225+<br><h4>Produktů v databázi</h4></h1></div>
                <div class="p-2 bd-highlight pr-4 pl-4 text-center"><h1>500+ <br></h1><h4>Spokojených zákazníků</h4></div>
                <div class="p-2 bd-highlight pl-4 text-center"><h1>105+ <br></h1><h4>Nových funkcí a úprav</h4></div>
                <div class="p-2 bd-highlight pl-4 text-center"><h1>2 <br></h1><h4>Kategorie produktů</h4></div>
            </div>
        </section> ``
```

Comment: Is this bootstrap 4? Bootstrap 3 does not have Bootstrap Spacing like `p-2` or `mb-3`. I've tested with bootstrap 3.3.1 and it works fine.

Comment: Bootstrap v3.x doesn't use Flexbox, you need to use Bootstrap v4.x

Comment: I am sorry, I edited the post. I am using version 4.4.1